# Books for functional equations

Tags: functional-equations

I am in high school and currently preparing for math Olympiad.
I want to study functional equations. I tried starting with B.J.Venkatachala's book but it seem way too advanced. What can I refer that starts from the basics and builds upto Olympiad level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book by B.J Venkatchala is very nice to start off, anyways if you have little or no experience then [Functional Equations and how to solve them](https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Functional%20Equations%20and%20How%20To%20Solve%20Them%20-%20Christopher%20G.%20Small.pdf) is a way out. Cheers!

Comment: You can refer to handouts also.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No problem anytime :)